# How can I correctly install qt5?

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, qt

I'm trying to upgrade from qt4 to qt5.  I was following a guide and it appears I have managed to install qt5.  As seen here...

```
daveomcd@ubuntu:~/Documents/rails_projects/bane$ dpkg -l qt5-qmake
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                          Version                     Architecture                Description
+++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-================================================================================================
ii  qt5-qmake:amd64                               5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1      amd64                       Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool
```

The guide mentioned doing `rm 'which qmake'` to remove the old install of qt4 at some point.  But know the software I'm trying to use that relies on qmake is no longer working.  I get the following error: `Command 'qmake ' not available`

Anyone know how I can resolve this issue?  Also it seems qt4 is still installed as well. As seen below.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                          Version                     Architecture                Description
+++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-================================================================================================
ii  qt4-qmake                                     4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2       amd64                       Qt 4 qmake Makefile generator tool
```

**Update:**
When I do... `qtchooser -l` I get the following:

```
4
5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the guide you have been following please?

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#ubuntu-trusty-1404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally they exist simultaneously.

List available versions:

```
$ qtchooser -l
4
5
default
qt4-i386-linux-gnu
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5.5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

Find out where it is:

```
$ qtchooser -qt=4 -print-env
QT_SELECT="4"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Use it with qmake:

```
$ qmake -qt=5 --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

For CMake set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to things like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/lib/cmake/` (for Qt installs from the package manager) or `/data/qt/Qt-5.5/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/` (that kind of structure comes from the manual installs).

Comment: when I try the qmake command I get `The program 'qmake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install qtchooser`. Though it appears qtchooser is already installed.

Comment: So I did `sudo apt-get install --reinstall qtchooser` and that corrected it.  I'm trying the software now... thanks!