# How do I install Qjackctl from source?

Tags: command-line, compiling

Please give exact code for:

```
./configure [--prefix=prefix]
```

I do not know how to put the prefix.

[The Qjackctl sourceforge page](https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/) states:

> The installation procedure follows the standard for source distributions. In the extracted source directory, just do:
>
> ```
> ./configure [--prefix=prefix]
> make
> ```
>
> and optionally as root:
>
> ```
> [sudo] make install
> ```
>
> This procedure will end installing the following files:
>
> ```
> prefix/bin/qjackctl
> prefix/share/applications/qjackctl.desktop
> prefix/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/qjackctl.png
> prefix/share/qjackctl/translations/qjackctl_*.qm
> prefix/share/man/man1/qjackctl.1
> ```
>
> Just launch `prefix/bin/qjackctl` and you're off (hopefully). Note that the default installation path prefix is `/usr/local`.

I tried it as below, but it fails...

```
kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~/Desktop$ ls
qjackctl-0.5.0  qjackctl-0.5.0.tar.gz
kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~/Desktop$ cd qjackctl-0.5.0
kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~/Desktop/qjackctl-0.5.0$ ./configure --prefix=/bin/qjackctl
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for g++ major version... 7
checking for qmake-qt5... no
checking for qmake... /usr/bin/qmake
checking for Qt major version... qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
0
configure: error: qmake-qt5 not found in current PATH. Maybe QT development environment isn't available. (qt5-devel)
kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~/Desktop/qjackctl-0.5.0$
```

How to correct this ?

Comment: unless you have a problem with it being installed in `/usr/local`, you don't need to give a prefix. The error might mean that you need to install `qt5-qmake`. Is there a reason you need to install `qjackctl` from source rather than from Ubuntu repositories (ie using `sudo apt install qjackctl` ?)

Comment: thanks, there is no Qjackctl  5.0 in repositories yet . It is the last version. 
But how to install  qt5-qmake ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? You can run `sudo apt install qt5-qmake` on 17.10... (But do you *need* the latest version of qjackctl?)

Comment: Thanks, I did  sudo apt install qt5-qmake , but I get :
configure: error: qmake-qt5 not found in current PATH. Maybe QT development environment isn't available. (qt5-devel)
kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~/Desktop/qjackctl-0.5.0$

Comment: I use  Ununtu studio 17.10.1

Comment: Well, actually I do not neet the latest version ,  version 4.5 works fine. I just anted to see how it looks

Comment: Oh... I don't know what it's complaining about then, sorry! Maybe somebody else will know what Qt dev packages etc are needed. The instructions aren't very specific... If I have time I'll try to look into it tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for your  comments ! If you succeed please inform me how.Best regards

Answer (score 3):

[Installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703864/cmake-not-working-could-not-exec-qmake#answer-44424883) [qt5-default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187231/i-need-a-minimal-qt-5-0-compiler-install-for-ubuntu-14-04-64bit#answer-32187390) did the trick for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

**Edit:** On a subsequent install of qjackctl on a clean Ubuntu 18.04 OS, **the above was all that was necessary to clear the error**. I'm leaving my original caveat below for reference.

One caveat, that was the last thing I tried and it worked. I'm unclear as to whether it alone would satisfy the requirements for installing qjackctl. Here are the other steps that I took prior to this working:

[Reinstall qtchooser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828662/how-can-i-correctly-install-qt5/828672#comment1260954_828672):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall qtchooser
```

That didn't seem to accomplish much. But then I [installed qt4-qmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703864/cmake-not-working-could-not-exec-qmake#answer-30564064):

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake
```

This eliminated the error that read `checking for Qt major version... qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory` but not the PATH error related to `qmake-qt5`

I then tried [installing some build requirements](http://www.rncbc.org/drupal/comment/7523#comment-7523):

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools libqt5x11extras5-dev
```

...which installed 37.0MB of components, but didn't resolve the error.

I also tried to [install build-essential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187231/i-need-a-minimal-qt-5-0-compiler-install-for-ubuntu-14-04-64bit#answer-32187390):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

...but found that it was already installed and up to date.

Finally, having seen more than one mention of qt5-default (see the beginning of my answer), I tried installing it and the PATH error was resolved.